# Is the approach for Audit logging in PostSharp 5.x changed?

Tags: postsharp

I see TODO in the link http://doc.postsharp.net/audit

Has there been a change in the way audit log works in 5.x? Or its the same as the article (published in 2011) http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/5-Ways-That-Postsharp-Can-SOLIDify-Your-Code-Logging-and-Auditing narrates ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the missing doc, we are working on it.

The custom auditing described in the article still works, but in PostSharp 5.0, we have come with a ready-made auditing aspect as a part of the improved Diagnostics Patterns Library - see https://www.postsharp.net/diagnostics.

The ready-made auditing pattern works as follows:

1) Install *PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics* NuGet package to your project.

2) Add the `AuditAttribute` custom attribute to all methods you want to be audited.

3) Register to the `AuditServices.RecordPublished` event, which would be fired every time an audited method is invoked.

An example showing this, among others, is available at http://samples.postsharp.net/#PostSharp.Samples.Logging/Program.cs.

Other resources:

- http://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_patterns_diagnostics_audit_auditattribute
- http://doc.postsharp.net/e_postsharp_patterns_diagnostics_audit_auditservices_recordpublished

Comment: Thanks.  In pre-5.x, MethodExecutionArgs.Arguments() returned only the arguments to the method. In 5.x, AuditRecordEventArgs.Record.Text() gives the functionname with arguments. How do I retrieve just the arguments of the method.

Comment: Retrieving the argument list via the `AuditRecord` class is not implemented at the moment. You can submit this as a feature request at https://postsharp.uservoice.com/.

Comment: Is AuditServices.RecordPublished a global event handler? I added this handler in main(). When [Audit] is added to a method in one of a dependent assembly the handler got called. Can you confirm that I don't have to register this event in all dependent assemblies?